# Benefit of postfix over prefix notation

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction

My compiler design professor said while evaluating a statement, we convert every token into postfix notation. Everything other than function calls are in infix notation, and therefore must be converted to postfix.However functions are in prefix and NOT infix notation. So they must be converted as well.
This can be demonstrated as `a+b` in infix being equivalent to `+(a,b)` or `+ab` in prefix notation.

However, I do not understand why we must convert everything to postfix and not prefix notation instead? Functions are already in prefix, so shouldn't it be faster to convert non function entities to prefix notation and execute in reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach your instructor is describing is one possible approach to parsing expressions, but it's not the only one. Fundamentally, the goal of parsing is to get the expression into a format that's easy to work with and interpret, and both prefix and postfix notations meet those requirements. In an actual compiler it's far more common to build an abstract syntax tree, a tree encoding the structure of the input, and you can think of both prefix and postfix notations as either a preorder or postorder walk of that tree.

As for efficiency - the actual difference in cost between using prefix and postfix notations are trivial and are not going to be the bottleneck in your compiler. Typically, the most time-intensive phase of a compiler is optimization, with parsing consuming very little time. I wouldn't worry about doing the efficiency of parsing until you have concrete evidence that it's causing a problem.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up the doubt. However, if I am going for an interpreter, will parsing and converting to postfix/prefix be a bottleneck for the system?

Comment: I seriously doubt it. The cost of parsing is a one-time hit, which almost certainly isn't the bottleneck. Generally, unless you're doing something absurdly inefficient during parsing, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Also, are you even sure that it's slower to do one than the other? I'm thinking over the algorithms I know for doing the conversions both ways and they should be roughly comparable in terms of runtime.

Comment: It SHOULD be slower (as in on paper). Since I am converting one type (in prefix) vs both (in post). However time should be pretty comparable since they its one time hit.